# Find root of project from included gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Here's the scenario. I'm writing `GemB`, and I plan to use it in `ProjectA`, but I want to write `GemB` in a non-specific fashion (as I should). I want `GemB` to look for a "config" file under a "conventional" `project_a/config/gem_b.yml`

If that file doesn't exist, `GemB` can default to it's own `gemb/config/default.yml`

`ProjectA` (probably is a variant of a gem/rails-engine/rails-app etc)
`GemB` (definitely a gem)

Is there a dynamic way for `GemB` to get the root of `ProjectA` (the project it's being used in)? If I could predict the name, I could call `ProjectA.root` (likely), so you might suggest calling `Rails.root` but I can't guarantee that it will be used in a `Rails` project, (and in this case unlikely anyway, based on the target functionality of `GemB`).

Trusting that's a sufficient explanation, let me know if I need to clarify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern gems don't look for a particular config file. Instead, they expect a config file of any name to be executed, which will set configurations via a `.config` variable on the gem's class name. For example, I might have this config file:

```
# config/initializers/ams.rb

ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :camel_lower
```

Now it doesn't matter where the file is located or what it's called. So long as the code is executed, ActiveModelSerializers can look at its own `ActiveModelSerializers.config` variable and it is good to go.

If you wanted an extensive configuration (by means of a .yml file, for example) you might create a `.config.path` setting and instruct users of your gem to set the path themselves and then create a file in the spot they choose:

```
# config/initializers/gem_b.rb

GemB.config.path = '/config/gem_b.yml'
```

Comment: Yea that's fair. I was leaning in that direction as well. I've already got a config block in the gem and was thinking about using that to allow a user to specify a config file. I should have specified, the "config" file I'm envisioning is more of a rich yaml file that would describe loads of application specific "policies". Thanks for the nudge, @moveson!